# Why would an answer posted by a 5 year user end up in the Late Answer New User queue?

Tags: discussion

I just reviewed [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98443/encrypting-files-and-folder-through-terminal/863650#863650) After suggesting minor improvements, my curiosity got the better of me and I checked the profile of the poster and discovered they have been a (granted mostly inactive) member for over 5 years! Is the queue misnamed? Should it be the Late Answer Low Rep queue?

Comment: [Link to Review Queue](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/656834) entry, if anybody's interested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the "new" refers to rep, and has nothing to do with how long a user has been a member. I don't know how the actual algorithm works, but I assume it's something along the lines of `if rep < N && isAnswerToOldQuestion; then...`. Or, perhaps, `if numberOfAnswers < N; then ...`.

So I wouldn't be surprised to find answers by users who've been here for years appear in the queue. Not if they haven't answered much before.

Comment: I would assume this to be an accurate assessment. Absent the actual algorithm it's hard to surmise much more. It does seem something of a misnomer though. Perhaps if I'd been more curious I'd have noticed this before. I was surprised to not find an answer on this topic already here.

Answer (score 2):

I signed up here over two years ago and at the time made a few posts but knew very little of how the AU interface worked or what the "UbuntuQuette" was in AU.

It wasn't until four months ago (after I bricked Windows 7) that I reinstalled Ubuntu and came back to AU. Through the process of resolving 14.04 laptop upgrade to 16.04 glitches I got very keen on learning new things and started answering questions.

So yes, I would say a "new user" has nothing to do with sign-up date but more so on rep points and more specifically learning the etiquette of properly formatted Questions, Answers and Comments.

Comment: I still think it's a bit of a misnomer...

Comment: Oh you are 100% correct... however the truth such as "You are a low rep user" doesn't sound so hot...LOL

Comment: I guess your right. That wouldn't "Be nice!"

Comment: Speaking of "nice" I think almost all the high rep users around here are nice and not at all condescending to "new users"

Comment: I would tend to agree with the "almost all" statement. It's been a couple years at least since I made that accusation (It wasn't nice but it was well deserved at the time)

Comment: I imagine most of the egotistical techies are on Windows Support Forums and making +100k / year feeling they don' t have the time for newbies or people who don't "rtfm".

Comment: I think sometimes people just let stress get the best of them and perhaps speak "in the moment". After all we're only human (not Vulcan) so we can't be completely logical all the time (as much as we may strive to be). My viewpoint is that you never know who might have the potential to become a fantastic member of the team and encouragement goes a lot farther than belittlement. I don't think I'm alone in appreciating the former and no one should have to put up with the latter. I don't think wages necessarily equate to ego but It likely has an impact.

Comment: Well said my friend.